# How I can say a specific line of text that I have list under a class?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm trying to make a graphic novelwith Object-oriented programming.
Actually, I'm focused on the battle part.

For some reason, the part where it's suppose to print a specific line it does not work, it would pass without doing anything, or I would get an error.

```
#Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ester\Desktop\Mercy or kill\Gamefalse.py", line 128, in <module>
    batalla_f1()
  File "C:\Users\Ester\Desktop\Mercy or kill\Gamefalse.py", line 94, in batalla_f1
    monstruo_escogido.frase_entre_atzar(7,9)
  File "C:\Users\Ester\Desktop\Mercy or kill\mercy_kill_classes.py", line 51, in frase_entre_atzar
    entre_atzar = self.frases.random.randrange (a,b)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'random'

#Code:
Drah_krow=Personaje("Drah Krow","monstruo",12,12,5,1,1)
Drah_krow.mostrar_todo()
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Señor de mediana edad con un cuchillo clavado bajo el cuello... Parece desorientado.")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- Echo de menos a alguien...")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- ¿Quien era? ¿Eras tú?.")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- Mi jefe me ordena cosas extrañas...")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- Quiere que te mate...")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- Oh, ya me acordé...¿Dondè estarà mi hija?")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- Me siento tan perdido que podría morir...")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- Me gustaria ir a la playa con el... ¿O era ella?")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- ¿Me conoces?")
Drah_krow.afegeix_frase("Drah Krow- No se donde estoy...")
Drah_krow.mostra_frases()

prota = Humano("Prota")


def batalla_f1():
    Drah_krow=Personaje("Drah Krow","fantasma",20,1,0)
    monstruo_escogido=Drah_krow
    prota.mostrar_todo()
    print("")
    monstruo_escogido.mostrar_todo()
    print("")
    z=0
    d=0
    q=0
    inici_hp = prota.hp
    inicim_hp = monstruo_escogido.hp
    while not((prota.hp<=0) or (monstruo_escogido.hp<=0)):
        print("Es tu turno:")
        z=z+1
        i = input("1.atacar 2.defender 3.Comprender")
        if(i=="1"):
            print("Tu- Atacas:")
            a = (prota.atk - monstruo_escogido.defe) 
            if (prota.atk < monstruo_escogido.defe): #  Ataque del prota es mas pequeño que la defensa del monstruo = anular ataque del prota
                a = 0
            if (a > monstruo_escogido.hp): # Vida del monstruo = 0 (Evitar numeros negativos en la vida del monstruo)
                a = monstruo_escogido.hp
            print ("Haces",a," de daño.")
            monstruo_escogido.hp = (monstruo_escogido.hp-a)
            print("La vida del mosntruo se reduce a",monstruo_escogido.hp)
            d=d+1
            prota.mostrar_todo()
            monstruo_escogido.mostrar_todo()
        elif(i=="2"):
            print ("prota defiende")
            a= random.randrange(5,50)
            if(prota.hp == inici_hp): 
                print("Tu hp ya está al máximo.")
            elif (prota.hp < inici_hp):
                print (a)
                if((a+prota.hp)> inici_hp):#si la suma del hp mas lo que se cura es mas grande que el hp original:
                    aa=(inici_hp -(a+prota.hp))              #restas el nuevo hp - hp original
                    prota.hp = inici_hp
                    print ("Te curas:",aa,"hp")
                    print("Tu hp sube a",prota.hp)
                    print("")
                elif((a+prota.hp)<inici_hp):
                    print ("Te curas",a,"hp")
                    prota.hp = (prota.hp + a)
                    print("Tu hp sube a",prota.hp)
                    print("")
            prota.mostrar_todo()
            print("")
            monstruo_escogido.mostrar_todo()
        elif(i=="3"):
            print("Prota actua:")
            a=input("1.Observar 2.Hablar 3.Llorar")
            if(a=="1"):
                print("Tu- Observas detalladamente:")
                monstruo_escogido.digues_frase_concreta(0)
            elif(a=="2"):
                print("Tu- Le dice que no quieres pelear...")
                if((z==0) and (d==0)):
                    monstruo_escogido.digues_frase_concreta(1)
                if((z==0) and (d!=0)):
                    monstruo_escogido.digues_frase_concreta(3)
                if((z==2) and (d==0)):
                    monstruo_escogido.digues_frase_concreta(2)
                    q=1
                if((z==2) and (d!=0)):
                    monstruo_escogido.digues_frase_concreta(4)
                elif((z!=0) or (z!=2)):
                    monstruo_escogido.frase_entre_atzar(7,9)
                if(q==1):
                    monstruo_escogido.digues_frase_concreta(5)
            elif(a=="3"):
                print ("Drah Krow parece confundido...")
                prota.incrementa_hp(5)
                print ("Te recuperas por 5 hp.")
        if not((prota.hp<=0) or (monstruo_escogido.hp<=0) or (q==1)):
            print("")
            print("Es el turno del monstruo:")
            print("")
            print("Monstruo ataca:")
            b= (monstruo_escogido.atk - prota.defe)#Daño real producido al final 
            if (monstruo_escogido.atk < prota.defe ): # Anular ataque del monstruo
                b = 0
            if (b > prota.hp):
                b = prota.hp
            print ("Monstruo hace",b," de daño.")
            prota.hp = (prota.hp-b)
            print("")
            prota.mostrar_todo()
            print("")
            monstruo_escogido.mostrar_todo() 
            print ("")
    if (prota.hp >0):
        print ("Tu ganas.")
        prota.kill =(prota.kill+1)
    elif (q==1):
        print ("Drah Krow parece volver un poco en si.")
        print ("Drak Krow desaparece tras un destello de luz blanca.")
        prota.mercy = (prota.mercy +1)
    elif(prota.hp == 0):
        print("Game Over")

batalla_f1()

#Class:

import random
class Personaje():
    def __init__(self, nom, especie="desconeguda", hp=0, atk=0, defe=0,mercy=0, kill=0):
        self.nom= nom
        self.especie= especie
        self.hp = hp
        self.atk = atk
        self.defe = defe
        self.mercy=mercy
        self.kill=kill
        self.frases=[]
    def mostrar_todo(self):   #mostra tots els atributs d'un personatge excepte frases
        print("Nom: ", self.nom)
        print("Especie:", self.especie)
        print("Hp:",self.hp)
        print("Atk:",self.atk)
        print("Def:",self.defe)
    def mostrar_todo_prota(self):
        print("Nom: ", self.nom)
        print("Especie:", self.especie)
        print("Hp:",self.hp)
        print("Atk:",self.atk)
        print("Def:",self.defe)
        print("Mercy:",self.mercy)
        print("Kill:",self.kill)
    def incrementa_hp(self, quantitat):  #mètodes per incrementar els diferents atributs
            self.hp = self.hp + quantitat
    def incrementa_atk(self, quantitat):
            self.atk = self.atk + quantitat
    def incrementa_defe(self, quantitat):
            self.defe = self.defe+ quantitat
    def incrementa_mercy(self, quantitat):
            self.mercy = self.mercy + quantitat
    def incrementa_kill(self, quantitat):
            self.kill = self.kill + quantitat
    def afegeix_frase(self, frase):  #mètode per afegir frases a la llista del personatge en concret
            self.frases.append(frase)
    def mostra_frases(self):   #mètode per mostrar totes les frases del personatge
            for frase in self.frases:
                print(frase)
    def digues_frase(self):    #dir una frase de la llista a l'atzar
        if (len(self.frases)!= 0):
            frase = random.choice(self.frases)
        else:
            frase= ("...")
        print(frase)
    def digues_frase_concreta(self, ordre):
        if(ordre<(len(self.frases))):
            print(self.frases[ordre])
    def frase_entre_atzar(self,a,b):
        entre_atzar = self.frases.random.randrange (a,b)
        print (entre_atzar)
    def ataca(self,oponent):
        print(self.nom,"ATACA A", oponent.nom)
        if (self.atk > oponent.defe):
            oponent.hp = (oponent.hp-1)
            print("Li has fet mal a", oponent.nom)
        else:
            print("No li has fet mal a", oponent.nom)

class Humano(Personaje):
    def __init__(self, nom):
        super().__init__(nom)     #hereda el nom de la classe Personatge
        self.especie="humano"     #fixa els atributs propis de la classe Humano
        self.hp=30
        self.atk=15
        self.defe=15
        self.mercy=0
        self.kill=0
        
class Bestia(Personaje):
    def __init__(self, nom):
        super().__init__(nom)
        self.especie="bestia"
        self.hp=15
        self.atk=30
        self.defe=15
        self.mercy=0
        self.kill=0

class DemiHumano(Personaje):
    def __init__(self, nom):
        super().__init__(nom)
        self.especie="demi-humano"
        self.hp=15
        self.atk=15
        self.defe=30
        self.mercy=0
        self.kill=0
```

I can't understand why it wok the part of "1.atacar 2.defender", but not the part of "3.Comprender".

Could you help me, please?

Also, Do you know any way to count the turns while the battle is going on, to say a different phrase each time the loop is restarted before one of the two characters dies?

(Sorry if some parts are in Spanish, if there something you don't understand, feel free to ask.)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, here's the line giving you error:

```
entre_atzar = self.frases.random.randrange (a,b)
```

random is not a data member of the the class of which frases is a member (which appears to a list) so you cannot use the dot operator to call a data member of the class that simply doesn't exist.

Normally,  `random.randrange(a,b)` will return a random number in the range between a and b.

So you have two options:

1) Get a number in a random range between a and b and then use that get the value at that index in the list:

`entre_atzar = self.frases[random.randrange(a,b)]`

2) Simply get a random value from a sub-list of the original list in that range:

`entre_atzar = random.choice(self.frases[a:b])`

I recommend the latter method, since I consider it to be cleaner and more intuitive, but both will yield the same result.

Comment: Yes but, Imagine that you have six sentences, sentence-1 sentence-2, sentence-3, sentence-4 and sentence-5, sentence-6. And I would like a random phrase to appear between phrase-3 and phrase-6, but neither phrase-1 nor phrase-2 should appear.
Would there be some way?

Comment: Sure, we can do that. I think the easiest way would be to make a random choice from a list that is a list containing that range of elements. Like this: `entre_atzar = random.choice(self.frases[a:b])`

Comment: That being said, your way would work also if you modify the syntax. `entre_atzar = self.frases[random.randrange(a,b)]`. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, i think I will us the`entre_atzar = random.choice(self.frases[a:b]) – Matthew Kligerman yesterday`.